# Upload custom text dataset to tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm attempting to create a text-classification model with tensorflow. There are many datasets you can import into a project using `tfds.load()`, but I want to create a unique dataset of my own. In tensorflow.js, all I had to do was create a JSON file with training/testing data. There doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this with python.

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ŧf.data.Dataset` is the place to be. Lil' pointer: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset. If your dataset fits into memory, you can go with `tf.data.from_tensor_slices` which lets you create a Dataset from numpy arrays. If not, `from_generator` might suit you, as you can write your generator in plain python. For the "correct" way to do it (this gives you the fastest pipeline in theory) you should save your data as `TFRecord`s and read them with `tf.data.TFRecordDataset`. Whatever floats your boat. Just click the link!

Comment: Thanks! All I want to do now is assign an array of strings to a true/false value. This can be done with a .txt file right?

Comment: Yes. Does your Dataset fit into memory?

Comment: Yes, for now it does.